# Aplicación que utilice una carpeta compartida para dlls

Tags: aplicación-escritorio, dll

Tengo un erp que cuyas instancias se utilizan en muchas computadoras y se vuelve cada vez mas complicado el tener que actualiza las aplicaciones que la conforman y consumen mucho ancho de banda el tener que estarlas actualizando cada vez que hay una liberación.
Podría cambiar las aplicaciones que conforman el ERP y hacer web services para efectos de las capas de negocios y datos, sin embargo, la aplicación es extensa y por ahora es poco viable al corto plazo.  Existe alguna manera de que pueda colocar los archivos dll de las librerías en una carpeta compartida de tal modo que las librerías sean manejadas en un solo lugar que solo los ejecutables y algunas librerías específicas en las máquinas estén localmente en cada estación, esto para efectos de que las actualizaciones sean más rápidas y fiables.  Si es así como podría hacerlo?
La aplicaciones son de escritorio y están desarrolladas en vb.net y se instalan en muchas puntos de red de la misma empresa.
De antemano muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: o sea.. analicemos tu solucion... en lugar de mandar todo el programa en una sola instalacion, estas esperando que cada vez que se ejecute, vaya a leer alguna (la que sea) dll a otro lado.. que implicaria, pedirla, transferirla por red, desencriptarla (de la red), guardarla en algun temporal del disco, cargarla a memoria... y eso  por cada ejecucion.. y eso suena mas rapido que simplemente instalar la aplicacion? capaz me perdi en algun momento de tu explicacion... ;)

Comment: Capaz lo que necesitas es que las actualizaciones sean automaticas, no?

Comment: En realidad no, veamos, normalmente cuando se hace una instalación, el instalador pone los dlls en carpetas determinadas y cuando el programa se ejecuta lee esos dll´s para realizar lo que tenga que hacer... la idea sería poder tener los dll´s que son comunes en una carpeta compartida de tal manera que en cada máquina no haya que estarlos instalando sino que es un área común donde todas las instancias leen, y si un dll cambia solo habria que modificarlo en un solo lugar y no en cada máquina que pueden ser muchas.
Mi pregunta es si eso sería viable y posible de hacer.

Comment: Algunas cosas, como por ejemplo los archivos de configuración, si deben ser locales al computador ya que implican cuestiones locales, pero en general los dlls son comunes a todas las instancias instaladas en todas las máquinas, entonces por que no tener un solo lugar en lugar y leerlo de ahí en lugar de estarlo "repitiendo" en todas las máquinas

Comment: Porque lo vas a estar repitiendo, quieras o no, en cada ejecucion!!! vas a transferir la dll entera, y vas a estar ejecutandola.. si lo que tenes, es un problema de instalacion, entonces tal vez, deberias revisar como estas haciendo las instalaciones... Tenes un windows por pc? o un windows que lee las dll comunes de un servidor comun ;) con tu navegador haces lo mismo? capaz, lo que tenes que revisar, es la estrategia de actualizacion del sistema. Los telefonos y los juegos lo hacen excelentemente bien....

Comment: es cierto que voy a estar transfiriendo, pero de forma diferida las dll y el programa solo va a leer en el momento las que ocupa y cuando las ocupa, ahora bien, la idea es no copiar todas esas dlls que representan miles de KB en transferencia de red una y otra vez (aunque sea compresos e incluidas en el instalador aunque no hayan cambiado) y que hacen que la red baje su rendimiento al punto de caerse por saturación.

Comment: Lo de cambiar la extrategia como lo mencioné antes está planificado para un largo plazo porque es un ERP, es complejo y toma tiempo pero el problema de las instalaciones por ahora se necesita resolver a un cortísimo plazo.

Comment: Por lo que se me ocurrió, que tal vez sería posible hacer algo similar al gac o archivos comunes, solo que en una carpeta compartida que sea leída no por los programas de una misma computadora si no por los de varias computadoras en la misma red. Supongo que si a mí se me ha ocurrido no es a la primera persona que se le haya ocurrido, por lo que quiero ver si existe algo con lo que se pueda implementar o ver si han habido inconvenientes cuales han sido concretamente, no como suposiciones sino como hechos concretos, y este pregunta forma parte de mi investigación.

Comment: "es cierto que voy a estar transfiriendo, pero de forma diferida las dll y el programa solo va a leer en el momento las que ocupa y cuando las ocupa" Esto no es cierto.. o vos escribiste todo el codigo behind para decidir cuando cargar cada cosa? me parece que estas suponiendo cosas que no son del todo reales... si yo apago el programa.. lo prendo.. lo apago.. lo prendo... la transferencia de todas las dll va a ocurrir siempre... y si la red se cae, debe ser por otro motivo... creo que nos estas mostrando lo que llamamos un problema A->B....